# Why is the Actionscript object converting the numeric strings in my php-returned XML output?

Tags: php, xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mxml

I'm sending a POST from flex to my php backend and the php code is returning this back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<rs>
  <action>getConfiguration</action>
  <num>1</num>
  <configuration>
    <armed>1</armed>
    <threshold>90.0</threshold>
  </configuration>
</rs>
```

That's fine, but when I access the parsed XML fields in my flex return handler through

```
var o:Object = event.result.rs.configuration;
```

I see (by stepping with FlashDevelop) that o.threshold is "90" instead of "90.0".

I need the "90.0".  Why is this conversion taking place, and how do I stop it?

Thanks for reading, and for any insights you can provide.

---

4/20/2016 Update:

Thanks for the first wave comments folks, I appreciate it.  I didn't want to fix the decimal places, it may be more than 1 place (e.g. 90.25), but I don't want "90.00".  I don't need to do any math on it, that's done on a different device, but I do need the .0 instead of numbers like 90.

The 90.0 goes on a form to be edited, and I want it to be a string.  I went ahead and tried these:

```
// fails
var num:Number = Number(event.result.rs.configuration.threshold);
var num2:Number = Number(o.threshold);
var num3:String = Number(o.threshold).toString();
var num4:String = String(o.threshold).toString();

// works
var num5:String = Number(o.threshold).toFixed(1).toString();
```

Nothing magical happened with Number(), which is expected, since examining the object showed that it held "90".  I would have expected that if "90.0" is in the XML and a generic object is used to access it, I'd see a string holding 90.0 (for what it's worth, it's also stored in a MySQL as TINYTEXT, but I don't see why that should matter given the XML output). 90.1 and 90.18 come back as 90.1 and 90.18.

I already knew I could treat it like a string, look for a '.', and if not present, concatenate ".0" to it so that my edit form would show what I want it to. But what is the smarter-than-me entity deciding that my 90.0 string should be stored as 90, and how do I tell it to cut it out?

---

4/21/2016 Update

After some searching / guessing building from Atriace response, I tried to have a more atomically performed XML parse, with

```
    var dataX:String = new XML(event.message.body).toXMLString();
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(dataX);
    var decode:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
    var resultObj:Object = decode.decodeXML(xmlDoc);
```

and still, I see that resultObj.rs.configuration.threshhold holds "90". I tried a few variations too, same thing.  It was nice to see that event.message.body had the 90.0, and it would be even nicer if something stopped deciding I want it turned into a number instead of a string.

Comment: What happens if you use `var n:Number = Number( event.result.rs.configuration);` does that give 90.0? Also shouldn't you be targeting `event.result.rs.configuration.threshhold`?

Comment: @VC.One your first suggestion cannot work because `event.result.rs.configuration` is not a Number, its a generic Object. Suggestion: `var treshhold:Number = Number(event.result.rs.configuration.treshhold);`

Comment: Or, since you need it as "90.0" you probably want to keep it as string: treshhold:String = Number(event.result.rs.configuration.treshhold); An alternative is to keep it as number (if you need it for calculations) and only alter the way it is displayed by using a NumberFormatter

Comment: @DodgerThud, thanks for spotting. Actually though the Asker's problem is just a rounding issue. That `o.threshold` entry is fine. It really is 90.0. @Trueskew consider `var num:Number = Number(o.threshhold).toFixed(1);`. Anyways `toFixed(n)` is your solution where _n_ is your required decimal places.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I replied to everyone, but it was a little long, so I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

As hard as it may be to swallow, all numerical representations of strings will resolve to the nearest relevant non-zero decimal point.  Therefore...

```
var a:Number = Number("90.010"); // 90.01
var b:Number = Number("90.000"); // 90
var c:Number = Number("00.100"); // 0.1
var x:String = Number("90.000").toFixed(1); // "90.0"
```

Be aware that this only happens when you cast the `String` as a `Number`, which is what you're explicitly doing above.  Still, you said this was happening "automatically" when your parser loaded the XML; this is disconcerting. Observe:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, readXML);
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("configuration.xml"));

function readXML(e:Event):void {
    var datum:XML = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);
}
```

The result of this load & create operation is as follows:

[image: A debugger printout of the contents of datum]

As you can see, the "90.0" is still there and stored as a `String`.  It should then be a simple matter of using the string in your UI (for the customer), and cast the value as a `Number` when you want to run calculations on the result.

I'd take a look at that parser of yours.  It appears to be doing more than you wanted.

Comment: Ignoring the 1st Update, I used `var o:Object = event.result.rs.configuration;` to access the incoming data, and you used `var datum:XML = new XML(e.currentTarget.data);`. I don't think I have a parser to check. I tried what you provided, but it failed at runtime since data wasn't a property (I'm using Flex 4.5). But with your hint, I see `event.currentTarget._result.configuration.threshold` is there, and it's "90". I did a new XML(event.message.body), and can see that the "90.0" made it. I'm not sure how to get at it though, I'll have to read more. Auto-convert still makes no sense. Thanks.